# Does cython support dataclasses or something similar

Tags: python, cython, python-3.7, namedtuple, python-dataclasses

I am interested in passing data between Python and Cython code so that the data are accessible from C and without GIL. I am thinking about achieving this using dataclasses (since py3.7), named tuples (with nice defining syntax since py3.6) or Cython's extension types (cdef classess).

Unfortunately, dataclasses and named tuples seem to be handled like generic objects from Cython without any support of being compiled into C.

Cython extension types (cdef classes) can be used, but they have many disadvantages compared to dataclasses, most importantly you have to implement `__init__` with boilerplate code for setting all your class attributes, right?

Comment: If you plan to use 3.x - why tag with python-2.7?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sorry, typo, fixed to 3.7!

Comment: Based on a quick look it appears that `dataclasses` is just a class factory module, with decorators and such that make it easier to create classes with common attributes or methods.  It doesn't, I think add any new class functionality.  I don't see the point in trying to use or implement it in `cython`.

Comment: Similarly, why use `namedtuples` in `cython`.  Why not simple tuples or lists?

Comment: @hpaulj Dataclasses and namedtuples allow writing much briefer and nicer code. And as I believe Cython aims to provide way to write nice pythonic code with C performance, it would be benefitial to support namedtuples or dataclasses in terms of compiling them to C.

Comment: Namedtuples are a fairly exotic python construct that uses a different metaclass than regular objects, I imagine it would be non-trivial to translate them properly. And, as hjpaulj said, dataclass isn't a proper class at all, it's a factory that allows you to generate classes in a slightly different way than usual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked Cython developers and they opened a feature request for implementing `@dataclass` for extension types (cdef classes): https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2903. So hopefully they will be supported in Cython soon.